# Prove this relation between truncated SVD and eigen decomposition?

Tags: matrices, svd

For a real matrix $M$, we have a full SVD $M=USV^T$ and a truncated SVD $M_{k}=U_kS_kV_k^T$.

The truncated SVD means (matlab grammar): $U_k=U(:,1:k), S_k=S(1:k,1:k), V_k=V(:,1:k)$.

Based on the truncated SVD, we have 
$U_kS_k=M_kV_k$.

But according to [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Singular_value_decomposition), there is $U_kS_k=MV_k$.

1. Now this is weird to me, how can you prove $M_kV_k=MV_k$ by derivation?
2. $U_kS_kV_k^T=MV_kV_k^T$. **Does this mean the $rank-k$ matrix approximation $M_k$ can be calculated by: $M_k=MV_kV_k^T$?**

Comment: Do you understand what's meant by "truncated" here? and how $M_k,U_k,S_k,V_k$ are related to $M,U,S,V$?

Comment: 1. Follows from $M=USV^T$ and the definition of the truncated quantities. 2. Yes. However, this is not how it should be calculated.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel What do u mean "this is not how it should be calculated"? If I only want an approximation not factorized matrices, does it have other disadvantages, maybe efficiency? I find it can be calculated by an eigendecomposition easily.

Comment: If you have $U_k$, $S_k$, and $V_k$ (as usual from SVD), there's no reason why to compute $M_k$ by $MV_kV_k^T$ instead of using directly the lower dimensional factors.